# Datatable custom html and class with array data source

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatable

I used https://datatables.net and my array:

```
var dataSet = [ ["1000", "1000_asd"], ["1001", "1001_qwe"] ];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.table').DataTable({
            aaData: dataSet,
            aoColumns: [
                { mDataProp: 0 },
                { mDataProp: 1 }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Now my table look like this:

> 1000    |    1000_asd
>
> 1001    |    1001_qwe

but i need display table with class and custom contents:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="id_1000">
        <td>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1000_asd_1.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1000_asd_2.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button>Check</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
```

How i can display table from array with html and class like that ?

Comment: So each `dataSet` key should be a `class`, and each value should be repeated 2 times as an image?

Comment: show me some code please

Comment: I know how to display datatable with Html Dom source, it simple just html and use `$('.table').DataTable();` but now i try to display datatable with a javascript object like this case. With object data source `$('.table').DataTable(.. what i need to do here ..);`

Comment: Can you give a full example of the javascript object (=literal) you intend to use?

Comment: Updated my jquery please help

Answer (score 0):

Found it :D
Hope this will help someone

```
$('.table').DataTable({
    "aaData": dataSet,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            "aTargets": [0], // select col 1
            "mData": 1, // dataSet[1]
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) { return '<img src="' + data + '_1.jpg" />';} //custom content
        },
        {
            "aTargets": [1], // col 2
            "mData": 1, // dataSet[1]
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) { return '<img src="' + data + '_2.jpg" />'; }
        },
        {
            "aTargets": [2], // col 3
            "mData": 0, // dataSet[0]
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) { return '<button class="' + data + '">Button</button>'; }
        },
    ],
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            $(nRow).addClass('trClass_' + aData[0]); // add class to <tr> aData = dataSet
    }
});
```